# Google Maps API Async Loading

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-loader

I am loading the Google Maps API script Asynchronously in IE9 using the following code:

```
function initialize() {
  ...
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

Now the thing is that when the script is fully loaded the `initialize()` function is called automatically. But when sometimes the user quota has been exceeded the `initialize()` function is not called and instead of map we see the plain white screen.

I want to detect this and fire my custom function which displays some alert like: `"Error!"`.

Can anyone tell me to how to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you sure `initialize()` is not called? If it isn't, there is nothing you can do because to do anything means changing the API code which you are receiving from Google. If your quota has been exceeded, you could try adding billing to your Google Console.

Comment: Oh...I thought if there is some specific solution to this problem. Well anyways Thanks Andrew.

Comment: I don't know what exactly happens when the quota has been reached, but maybe it could work when you observe the `onerror`-event of the loaded  script.

Comment: Sir...I tried it but I think onerror doesn't seems to work in IE9! Also if I try to call initialize() function from script.onload event nothing happens at all. I mean the map isn't loaded and what all I can see is plain white screen. Could you suggest an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew mentioned, there isn't a direct way to handle this. However, you can at least account for the possibility.

Set a timeout for a reasonable time frame (5 secondes?). In the timeout callback function, test for the existence of google and/or google.maps. If it doesn't exist, assume the script load failed.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  if(!window.google || !window.google.maps) {
    //handle script not loaded
  }
}), 5000);
// Maps api asynchronous load code here.
```

Comment: I tried this snippet but it didn't work if we put it in the callback function as the callback function is never called when script fails to load!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution for this problem. Chad gave a nice solution but the only thing is that you can't put that piece of code in the `callback()` function because if the script fails to load the `callback()` function is never called!

So based on what Chad has mentioned I finally came up with the following solution:

```
function initialize() {
  ...
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE&callback=initialize";
  setTimeout(function () {
        try{
            if (!google || !google.maps) {
                //This will Throw the error if 'google' is not defined
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            //You can write the code for error handling here
            //Something like alert('Ah...Error Occurred!');
        }
    }, 5000);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

This seems to work fine for me! :)

Comment: It throws an error only if you use google instead of window.google