# google map not showing in page by ajax loaded content

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have main.html page and I am calling sub pages in main.html like this:

main.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getmyurl(url){
$('#mypageload').load(url);
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getmyurl('googlemap.htm');">google map</a>
<div id="mypageload">html page content will come to here like php include</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working good for normal pages. But google map (googlemap.htm) didn't show to map. I guess problem here:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

What can I do for fix problem?

googlemap.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function initialize() {
....
}
</script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: My English is not good, I am sorry for the miskates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error I get with your code (best I can replicate it) is:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

You can fix that by [asynchronously loading the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687237/google-maps-api-async-loading):

```
function loadScript(src,callback){

  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  if(callback)script.onload=callback;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  script.src = src;
}
loadScript('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=initialize');
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeo1aocu/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and helpful examples. I fixed now my problem.

Comment: Your suggestion did not work for me, but in any case it looks like you have a typo in your sample code.  The callback should be a second parameter, not part of the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Since Google Maps supports *async* loading you could achieve it by applying the following changes:

Replace in `googlemap.htm` file the line:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize&sensor=false&libraries=places" async defer></script>
```

Since `callback` parameter specifies the name of function that is invoked once Google Maps library is loaded, comment (or delete) in `googlemap.htm` file:

```
//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```