# Google Map not displayed in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I've a php file that generates a map (GoogleMap). If I run it independently (http://localhost/domain/map.php) it works properly.

But when I try to display it via Ajax call it displays all the map.php content less the map.

```
$.ajax({            
        type:"post",
        url:"map_generator.php",                
        data:{label1:data1},                    
        success:  function (response) {                 
            $('#map-section').html(response);

        },          
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
```

I also tried with 'complete' function instead of 'success' but still not working.

All hints are welcomed.

Thank you

---

EDITED

My map.php

```
<html>
<head>

<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

var coords = [{
0: "45.648110",
1: "11.497398",
2:"Title 1"
}, {
0: "45.511180",
1: "11.511070",
2:"Title 2"
 },{

0: "45.803245",
1: "11.355629",
2:"Title 3"
}];

var geocoder;
var map;

var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(coords [0][0], coords [0][1]);


function initialize() {
//Google map option
        var googleMapOptions = 
        { 
            center: mapCenter, // map center
            zoom: 7, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
            panControl: true, //enable pan Control
            zoomControl: true, //enable zoom control
            zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
        },
            scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), googleMapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mapCenter,
            map: map                
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:"¡Hello World!"
        });

    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    update(coords )
}


function update(markers) {
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var lat = markers[i][0];
        var lng = markers[i][1];    

        var title = markers[i][2];                                  

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map: map,               
            title: title
        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, lat, lng) {

                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(lat + " " + lng);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, lat, lng));

    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

</head>                 
<body>

<div class="map" id="map" style="margin:0 auto; width:500px; height:500px; border:1px solid #ff0000">


</body>

</html>
```

And this is the file that calls the map.php

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">     </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>   
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/informe.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getMap()">Get map</a>
 <div id="map-section" style="position:relative; border:1px solid;width:600px; height:600px;"></div>

 <script>

 function getMap(){ 

$(document).ready(function(){       
    $.ajax({            
        type:"post",
        url:"map.php",              
        data:{region:"algo"},                   
        success:  function (response) {                     
            $('#map-section').html(response);   
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}); 
 }

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: is the `map.php` a self contained, properly formed, html page (with html, head, body etc tags)? Also, have you checked the Developer Tools console (developer tools on most browsers is **F12** on the keyboard)

Comment: Yes, it is properly formed. I tried loading the scripts before the call (as said here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426165/google-map-not-showing-in-page-by-ajax-loaded-content) , but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: have you checked the Developer Tools console for errors (developer tools on most browsers is **F12** on the keyboard)

Comment: It  shows the following: Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages

Comment: I removed sensor=false from <script> but still not working. I begin to suspect that may be ajax call needs some more time to draw the map and thats why it doesn't display it.

Comment: `I begin to suspect that may be ajax call needs some more time to draw the map` - not likely

Comment: I'm getting now this error: 'google is not defined' and the lane of the error is : var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(coord[0][0], coord[0][1]);

Comment: Please show you map.php code..

Comment: I already edited the post so u can test the codes.